# Can't catch touch event of Child View of Header of Sticky Header (RecyclerView) by eowise

Tags: android, sticky, android-recyclerview

I'm using library "recyclerview-stickyheaders" link here : https://github.com/eowise/recyclerview-stickyheaders
Everything is ok, I can't catch touch event by .setOnHeaderClickListener(this) use StickyHeadersBuilder class. But I can't and I don't know how to implement click listener for child view of "header" ( textview, button in header ), in this case is btnFollow. It always catch touch event for whole "header". I try to implement click listener for class ViewHolder of Header on ( HeaderAdapter ) but it doesn't work.
* In MainActivity :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_timeline);
    adapterRecyclerView = new AdapterRecyclerTimeline(getApplicationContext(), getData());
    adapterRecyclerView.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    adapterHeader = new AdapterTimelineHeader(getApplicationContext(), getData());
    adapterHeader.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerHeader = new StickyHeadersBuilder()
            .setAdapter(adapterRecyclerView)
            .setRecyclerView(recyclerView)
            .setStickyHeadersAdapter(adapterHeader)
            .setOnHeaderClickListener(this)
            .build();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRecyclerView);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(recyclerHeader);

}

@Override
public void onHeaderClick(View header, long headerId) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Header Clicked LIB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void headerClicked(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Header Clicked MANUAL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

- In AdapterHeader

  public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
      RelativeLayout profile;
      TextView tvProfileName;
      TextView btnFollow;

  ```
  public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      profile = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile);
      tvProfileName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_profile_name);
      btnFollow = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_follow);
      btnFollow.setOnClickListener(this);
      L.m("Set Listener FOLLOW");
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
      if (clickListener != null) {
          L.m("Do Click FOLLOW");
          clickListener.headerClicked(v, getPosition());
      }
  }
  ```

  }
  public interface ClickListener {
      public void headerClicked(View view, int position);
  }

  public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
      this.clickListener = clickListener;
  }
- Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This libraries do not actually add any view to the screen - only copies **pixel by pixel** view to canvas. Here is the code:

```

```
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(0, y);
header.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

```

So your header is not actually on the screen - only it`s visual clone.

It is possible to handle clicks on parent view - see this [library](https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/timehop/stickyheadersrecyclerview/StickyRecyclerHeadersTouchListener.java) (it looks like practically the same)

But from parent view it will be extremely difficult to send click event to child (for example buttons in). And of course no animation because what you see is actually not view.